# Serve static content in Stoplight Prism mock server

Tags: openapi, stoplight

I have OpenAPI file describes my API design, using the Stoplight Prism to provide a mock server for the front-end developers by their Docker image stoplight/prism:4

My question is, how can I serve static content within that server?

I need to provide an API documentation for the front-end developers to know how to use the API, I have this documentation as HTML file, for now I serve this documentation by a separate web server, how can I include it within Prism?

All my API endpoints are available  at /api/ path, can I serve my HTML file at something like /static/doc.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism CLI doesn't support serving static file. A simple approach is to use Docker Compose to start the mock server and web server.

Below example bases on the way described in [Serving Multiple OpenAPI Documents](https://meta.stoplight.io/docs/prism/4bf78efbf9dd2-serving-multiple-open-api-documents), to use Caddy as both reverse proxy and static file server.

```
❯ tree
.
├── Caddyfile
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── html
│   └── index.html
└── myapi.yaml
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: caddy
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - ${PWD}/html:/var/www/static
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - prism
  prism:
    image: stoplight/prism:4
    volumes:
      - ./myapi.yaml:/usr/src/prism/packages/cli/myapi.yaml
    command: >
      mock -p 4010 --host 0.0.0.0 myapi.yaml
```

Caddyfile:

```
http:// {
    root * /var/www
    reverse_proxy /api/* prism:4010
    file_server /static/*
}
```

After run the command `docker-compose up`, you can view document on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/static` and call API on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/...`.